# How to work with ParameterNameAware

Tags: java, parameters, struts2

I am learning S2 and working on an application, now I want to use ParameterNameAware in my action class, but before that I just want to clarify some questions to myself. Please help me...

1. How ParameterNameAware works (has basic knowledge but want explanation)
2. How often acceptableParameterName is called
3. when I executed the application and trying to print the parameter(string) from acceptableParameterName method, it returning more than the input parameters. what are they and what this method provides actually.
4. what are the best ways to avoid unacceptable parameters(apart from ParameterNameAware).

please ignore if any of these questions doesn't make sense.

more explanation will be really appreciated. Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1):

Well here are few inputs to make your points more clear.

The whole idea about this interface is to maintain a list of valid parameter names and there by rejecting any request parameters that are not in this list.

If you want your action to accept only certain set of values, all you need to implement `ParameterNameAware` interface in your action to pass a message to underlying S2 framework that you want to accept certain set of parameters only for your action class.

`Parameters Interceptor` gets all parameters from A`ctionContext.getParameters()` and sets them on the value stack by calling `ValueStack.setValue(String, Object)`.
`ParameterNameAware` works in conjunction with `ParametersInterceptor.`While setting the parameters in your action class, if the interface has been implimented by your action class, Interceptor check if the parameter is allowed in your action class or not and will set only allowed parameters.

Other way to handle blacklisting or white-listing of the parameters is to pass list of `acceptParamNames` or `excludeParams` as Parameters to your `ParametersInterceptor`.